# how to optimize the state value in useSelector() react

Tags: reactjs, redux

Please let me know how I can optimize better way for useselector:

```
 const {
    addressList,
    deleteUserAddress,
    favouriteAddress,
    userAddressAfterUpdate,
    details,
    tokens,
  } = useSelector((state: RootState) => ({
    addressList: state?.address?.addressList,
    deleteUserAddress: state?.address?.deleteUserAddress,
    favouriteAddress: state?.address?.favouriteAddress,
    userAddressAfterUpdate: state?.address?.userAddressAfterUpdate,
    details: state.user.details,
    tokens: state.user.tokens,
  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could:

```
 const {
    address,
    user
  } = useSelector((state: RootState) => ({
    address: state?.address,
    user: state?.user
  }));
```

And then when needed you could call `address.addressList` or `user.tokens`.